# How may I add a tab item in an OG that shows a Content Type related to that group?

Tags: organic-groups, 7

We have Drupal Commons 3 (on Drupal 7). In our groups, I'd like at add a tag near the group's title that links to a certain content types. I have a View ready to go. How might I add that view to an OG tab?

**Update and screen shots:**

So I have this view: 
[image]

I had hopped to create a new tab here:

[image]

By playing with this setting:
[image]

Comment: Instead of creating a tag near the group title, you can create a menu item(MENU_LOCAL_TASK) and show the view inside that. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Yes! How might I do that for the view? I'm happy to post more screen shots of the view if that helps.

Comment: Means you need to create a menu item using VIEWS or Programmatically ? And screenshot will be helpful..

Comment: Preferably, using views to create the menu item. I've added screen shots.

Comment: To show on the group page you need to use node/%/YOUR_path NOT groups/%/about. I have updated my answer(Programmatically and using VIEWS) you can refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7, you can achieve this using creating a new MENU item via programmatically OR by VIEWS.

Programmatically:

- Create a menu item

  `function test_menu() {
    ....
    //menu for shows a Content Type related to that group
    $items['node/%/og-content-type'] = array(
    'title' => 'OG content type',
    'page callback' => 'get_og_content_type',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'og_content_type_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 5,
    );
    ...
    return $items;
  }`
- Now give access to the tab

  `function og_content_type_access($etid) {
    if (access) {//check your condition. Based on this condition the TAB will show.
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }`
- Now its time to embed your view

  `function get_og_content_type($etid) {//Im passing ID in case you want in views.
    $html = '';
    $html = views_embed_view('VIEWNAME', 'display_id', $etid);//embed view
    return $html;
  }`

Reference : [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

**Using Views**:

- Just create a new VIEW, with path as **node/%/YOUR_PATH**, **Contextual filters** and **Permission**. Refer the images below

  [image]
- Create a NEW menu TAB now

  [image]
- Add Contextual filters, based on this filter the VIEWS content changes.

  [image]
- Final result

  [image]

To create a custom permission in VIEWS, you can use **PHP filter**.

- Go to admin > modules and enable **PHP filter**
- Go to your VIEW >> **Page settings >> Access** and select PHP filter and add this code without **PHP TAGS**.

    `if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $entity_type = 'node';
      $etid = arg(1);
      if ($group = og_get_group($entity_type, $etid)) {
        return TRUE;
      }
      else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }`

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]

NOTE :

- You can create you own permission using [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) and you can use that permission in VIEWS >> **Page settings >> Access**

Comment: Thanks. I may hold this in reserve, but I'd prefer not to use code at the moment.

Comment: I have updated the answer using views to create the menu item :)

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Or in this situation an upvote and a marked correct answer. Thanks a million. I appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: Only difference is that I changed the context filter to Organic Group ID.

Comment: I am having this tab now appear on every piece of content. How can I constrain to only Groups (OG)?

Comment: The TAB will show based on the permission. Check your permission for the tab. OR create a new permission  using PHP filter. Go to admin > moudles enable "PHP FILTER". Come back to your view you will see php filter in  VIEWS >> Page settings >> Access. select it and check the condition based on your requirement and return TRUE OR FALSE. Ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I lack the requisite reputation points to comment (really?) but I wanted to call out Richard's remark about using the Group ID in the contextual filter rather than the Node ID.

A group is a node, yes, but I just completed this exercise and it refused to work with *Content: NID* as the contextual filter. When I changed it to *OG Membership: Group ID* I began to get the expected view results:

[image]